# The homomorphic image of an abelian group is abelian

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-homomorphism

We learnt about **Group Homomorphisms** and **Abelian Groups**, but never have we been shown how to tackle such question....and I have an exam on this tomorrow.

The question says:

> Let $\phi : G \rightarrow H$ be a group **epimorphism**. Prove that if $G$ is Abelian, then $H$ is Abelian.

You don't necesseraly have to give me the answer. Just how to go about it.

Comment: @Tsemo Aristide -  Well I saw that for it to be an Epimorphism, the mapping must be Surjective. But normally I'm given the value of $\phi (g) ,  g\in G$

Comment: Thats about it haha. I'm really lost.

Comment: Write down the definition. You want two elements $a,b \in H$ to commute. Pull them back to $G$ using the epimorphism $\phi$, commute them in $G$ (which is abelian), and push them forward to $H$ again through $\phi$.

Comment: @A.P. - Ahh, see when I wrote down the definition, everything was clear and I realised the question wasn't hard in the first place :) . Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the fact that any $h_1,h_2\in H$ can be written $h_1 = \phi(g_1),h_2 = \phi(g_2)$ for some $g_1,g_2\in G$.

Comment: Thank you. This helped a lot the test went really well thanks to the help you guys have :).

Answer (score 1):

Given $f:G\to H$ be an epimorphism, 
let $a,b$ be two elements of $H$ then there exists $x,y$ in $G$ such that:

$a=f(x) , b=f(y)$.
Therefore,
$ab = f(x)f(y)
=f(xy)
=f(yx) 
=f(y)f(x)
=ba$

Therefore $ab = ba$

Hence $H$ is also abelian.